# Why a MP4 H.264 video looks fuzzy on Google Chrome but sharp on Firefox?

Tags: google-chrome, video, video-conversion, video-encoding, h.264

This is the file I am trying to open directly into Chrome (It happens on websites but it seems the problem is with the rendering engine)

http://wikisend.com/download/914020/pipe-handbreak.mp4

It doesn't matter if I play as a local file or hosted, but chrome is rendering fuzzy/blurry video. I have tried turning off all extensions and removing hardware acceleration and it doesn't change anything. It seems that there is no relationship with screen, because I replicated the problem in two completely different computers.

[image: screenshot comparison of video rendered on Firefox and Chrome]

Chrome version: Version 59.0.3071.115 (Official Build) (64-bit)
OS: Windows 10
Video Source: MP4 using H.624 codec with maximum quality

Comment: I think I found the problem. The H264 codec needs to follow sizes that are proportional to 8 or 16: x264 video codec perform better when the width and height in pixels are multiples of 8 or 16.